# How to get UniqueDeviceID in Ionic 3 without need for a special permission?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, android-permissions, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I am using the code provided in the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/unique-device-id/) to get a unique identifier for the device:

```
getDeviceUniqueId() {
    this.uniqueDeviceID.get()
        .then((uuid: string) => this.uniqueDeviceIdStr = uuid)
        .catch((error: any) => {
            this.uniqueDeviceIdStr = "N/A";
            this.loggingService.logError("Error getting device unique identifier", error);
    });
}
```

However, when this code is executed the following message is displayed:

> Allow  to make and manage phone calls?

I am testing against an Android device (version 6.0.1) and my application does not require this permission for any other functionality. Removing the code also removes this permission requirement dialog.

The unique identifier is properly displayed if I grant the app the requested permission.

**Question:** How to get `UniqueDeviceID` in Ionic 3 without need for a special permission?

Comment: You could use the Cordova Device plugin to get uuid without requiring any permission: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device/#uuid

Comment: @99tharun - I will use that instead, although it does not return the same identifier. `uniqueDeviceID` returned by above promise includes `uuid`. It looks like `{uuid}-{some other numeric identifier}`. Thanks.

Comment: @Alexei Heres some info on how it's generated: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/#deviceuuid